# HOW TO: Select inside INSERT on php to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Hellos guys,

im having a problem. I want to insert 2 values to a database my problem is that one of the values must come from another table, heres the code:

```
//Selecionar tabela UVIndex da DB
$sql = "INSERT INTO praia (nome_praia) VALUES ('$nome_praia'); INSERT INTO utilizador (nome_utilizador, password_utilizador, nome_praia) VALUES ('$nome_utilizador', '$password', (SELECT FROM praia (idPraia) WHERE nome_praia=' .$nome_praia)";


$result = $conn->multi_query($sql)


$conn->close();
```

whats my problem?

Comment: can you add the missing semi-colon here `$result = $conn->multi_query($sql)` << Some may think your code failed because of it, believe me I've seen it before.

Comment: yeah i have that my error... now i can pass the values to praia table but the table utilizador has nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a insert into select statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name)
SELECT column_name
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you select return a single result only You should use a valid select however .

`SELECT  idPraia FROM praia  WHERE nome_praia=  '$nome_praia'`

```
 "INSERT INTO praia (nome_praia) VALUES ('$nome_praia'); 
   INSERT INTO utilizador (nome_utilizador, password_utilizador, nome_praia) 
   VALUES ('$nome_utilizador', '$password', (SELECT  idPraia FROM praia 
                                               WHERE nome_praia=  '$nome_praia' ));";
```

Comment: im returning a value from a form. in  that form i pass the name, password and nome praia. when i run the php i can fill the table Praia in database but the table utilizador doesnt have any values

Answer (score 0):

I Think yours table "utilizador" should have a foreign key field "idPraia" rather than "nome_praia" field. Then use the following code , whereas the key field name of the table "praia" is "idPraia".

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO praia (nome_praia) VALUES ('$nome_praia'); INSERT INTO utilizador (nome_utilizador, password_utilizador, idPraia) VALUES ('$nome_utilizador', '$password', (SELECT idPraia FROM praia WHERE nome_praia='$nome_praia')";
```